# What is explicit isomorphism in bicategory of algebras, bimodules and bimodule homomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, tensor-products, higher-category-theory

If we take the Morita bicategory which has k-algbras as objects, bimodules as 1-morphisms and bimodule maps as 2-morphisms, then what would the unitors be explicitly? For algebra $A$, I can take the evaluation and coevaluation 1-morphisms to be $_{A \otimes_k A^{op}}A_k$ and $_kA_{A^{op} \otimes_k A}$ respectively. So would the unitors be $_AA_{A\otimes_k k }$ and $_{A\otimes_k k }A_A$ respectively?

If so, then what should the explicit construction of the cusp isomorphisms, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in following picture, be?

[digram of required isomorphism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrapJ.png)

Ignoring the unitors and associators in the diagram, one answer I have is the following:
$$\alpha : (E \otimes id) \circ (id \otimes C) \rightarrow id$$ $$ (_AA_A \otimes_{k} \ _kA_{A^{op} \otimes_k A}) \otimes (_{A \otimes_k A^{op}}A_k \otimes_k \ _AA_A) \rightarrow _AA_A$$ $$(a_1 \otimes a_2) \otimes (a_3 \otimes a_4) \mapsto a_1a_3a_2a_4$$

However there is the issue of what the $\alpha^{-1}$ would be in this situation. Since each permutation of the 4 factors would map to something different under $\alpha^{-1}$, how do I show that it is all the same, i.e, well defined no matter if I start with $a = a_1a_2a_3a_4$ or $a = a_4a_2a_1a_3$ and apply $\alpha^{-1}$? How should I define $\alpha^{-1}$ **explicitly**?

Comment: I know of a bicategory of rings, bimodules and bimodule homomorphisms. Do you have a reference where your bicategory is described/defined? Or does it help you, if I describe my bicategory explicitly instead?

Comment: @Merle the bicategory is described here for example : 
 https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.04866   The cusp isomorphisms diagram I am trying to work out is in the initial chapter here :  https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.6691

Comment: @Merle yes the bicategory you mention would be helpful if explained. It will be nearly the same thing anyway. So what would the cusp morphisms be explicitly in the bicategory of rings, bimodules and bimodule maps?